# How to make a synchronous GET request in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, recursion

JS code:

```js
function saveCategories(i){
    var categoriesList=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("categoriesList"));
    var code=localStorage.getItem("gameCode");

    if(i == categoriesList.length)
        return;

    var categoryName=categoriesList[i]['name'];
    var items=categoriesList[i]['items'];

    $.get('http://localhost:8080/yourfolder/newCategory.php',{GameCode:code,items:items,CategoryName:categoryName},function(resp)
        {
            saveCategories(i+1);
        });
}
```

PHP code:

```php
<?php 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");

$host="127.0.0.1";
$user="root";
$pass="password";
$databaseName="games";

$con=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass,$databaseName);

if(!$con)
{
    die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}

$code=$_GET["GameCode"];
$name=$_GET["CategoryName"];
$items=$_GET["items"];

$data=array();
foreach($items as $item)
    $data[]=addcslashes($item);
$data=implode(",",$data);

$sql="INSERT INTO games.categories(code,name,items) VALUES ('$code','$name','$data')";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$con);

echo $result;
?>
```

The php file (**newCategory.php**) should get code, category name and category items and insert them to MYSQL db.

The `saveCategories` recursive function should get the **newCategory.php** file for each category (in index i), but for some reason, it proceed to the next iteration without getting a result from the first `GET` request before.

The unwanted result is that the first category in index 0 is not saved in the MYSQL db.

Comment: Hi, just one query where it the saveCategories method called for the first time (i.e. saveCategories(0)), initially called.

Comment: I call the saveCategories function in this way:saveCategories(0) and the first category should be saved.

Comment: Hi, I would suggest you to first print the response of the API in JS before you call the saveCategories(i+1); method. Then post the response here that might help you and us to solve the problem.

Comment: The response is 1 for each category.That's because I print the result of mysql_query($sql,$con); in the php code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get jQuery to perform a synchronous, rather than asynchronous, Ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re)

Answer (score 1):

use `async: false` in your data

example:

```
 $.ajax({
    url : "/your url",
    type : "get",
    async: false,
    success : function(userStatus) {
       //your logic
    },
    error: function() {

    }
 });
```

Comment: I get this warning:"jQuery has deprecated synchronous XMLHTTPRequest", and it still doesn't save the first category.

Comment: synchronous requests on the main thread have been deprecated due to the negative effects to the user experience.

Comment: you can debug this code by putting breakpoint  before calling saveCategory(i+1)
you will have to check for `i` Value as well as the response data i.e. `resp'.

Comment: I get a good response for each i, but the first category is not saved.

Comment: what, how and where are you trying to save?

Comment: I am trying to save code, category name and category items in MYSQL db for each category with the newCategory php code above.

Comment: whats initial value of `i` you are passing when first time you are calling `saveCategories`

Comment: The initial value is:0

Answer (score 0):

referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re) answer you can specify the asynchronous option to be false to get a synchronous Ajax request using jquery. You just need to specify

```
{async:false}
```

[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) article shows how to do it using a XMLHttpRequest().